# Prestashop Webservice to add simple product

Tags: php, web-services, import, prestashop, product

I am writing a script that will add products through the webservice.
I`m having some dificulties for a couple of hours so I seek for help.
This is what I have now.

```
require_once("config.php");
require_once("PSWebServiceLibrary.php");

try {

    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(SITE_URL, WEBSERVICE_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG_MODE);
    $xml = $webService->get(array('url' => SITE_URL.'/api/products?schema=synopsis'));
    $product = $xml->children()->children();
    $product->price = 99; 
    $product->wholesale_price = 89; 
    $product->active = '1';
    $product->on_sale = 0; 
    $product->show_price = 1;
    $product->available_for_order = 1;

    $product->name->language[0][0] = "Produit webservice";
    $product->name->language[0][0]['id'] = 1;
    $product->name->language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = SITE_URL . '/api/languages/' . 1;

    $product->description->language[0][0] = "Description produit webservice";
    $product->description->language[0][0]['id'] = 1;
    $product->description->language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = SITE_URL . '/api/languages/' . 1;

    $product->description_short->language[0][0] = "Descr. courte";
    $product->description_short->language[0][0]['id'] = 1;
    $product->description_short->language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = SITE_URL . '/api/languages/' . 1;
    $product->reference = "ref_product_webservice";

    $product->depends_on_stock = 0; 

    $category_id = 3;
    $product->associations->categories->addChild('category')->addChild('id', $category_id);
    $product->id_category_default = $category_id;

    //
    $opt = array('resource' => 'products');
    $opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
    $xml = $webService->add($opt);   
}
catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
    echo "Error:<br>";
    echo  $ex->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}
```

I have my webservice all set up , but I keep getting this error :

> This call to PrestaShop Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 500. That means: Internal Server Error.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Activate the display error, follow [the documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/System+Administrator+Guide#SystemAdministratorGuide-defines.inc.phpfile) to know how you can do. If that didn't guide you to resolution read the server log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the schema to blank , and now it`s working.
The initial error was:

> Attribute "href" bound to namespace

Answer (score 0):

Enable debug mode in your Prestashop. You will receive exactly which field are you setting wrong and why.

[Enable Pretashop debug mode](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/285199-how-to-enable-debugging-mode-in-prestasho-156/)

Good luck.